# Given that $f$ is a quadratic function with minimum $f(x)=f(3)=2$, find the axis, vertex, range, and $x$-intercepts.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

College freshman here who sucks at math. Can someone please explain and answer this for me?

Comment: What are your own thoughts so far?

Comment: @Théophile Been trying to figure this out for a while. Guessing that the vertex is (3, 2) but definitely wrong. I also need to know the equation of the axis which I do not know how to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

1. You have a quadratic function, so $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. Plug in $f(2)=3$ to get an equation for $a,b$ and $c$.
2. Since $f$ has a minimum, is $a$ positive or negative?
3. Minimum of $f$ should be at $x = -b/2a$. The minimum of $f$ is at $2$, what is a simple equation connecting $a$ and $b$?
4. Combine equations from (1) and (3) to reduce the parabola to one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A parabola facing up
with low point at the origin
is
$y = ax^2$
for some $a > 0$.

If the low point
is at $3$,
the equation is
$y = a(x-3)^2$.

If the value at $3$
is $2$,
the equation is
$y = a(x-3)^2+2$.

I don't see 
how to determine $a$
from the information given.